# WPF Property Data binding to negate the property - initial value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create just two buttons: [Login] and [Logout] of which only one will be enabled in the same time.

I need to use binding - IsEnabled property of each of the buttons will be bound to another button's property with negation using converter.

I approached interesting problem: how to set the initial values of IsEnabled?

Answer (score 2):

I would bind both buttons to a code-behind property `LoggedIn`. If `LoggedIn` is `false`, the login button is enabled and the logout button is disabled (using the negating converter). Each button would set the `LoggedIn` property to the respective value.